# Need a case insensitive collation where ss != ß

Tags: sql-server, collation

For a specific column in a database running on SQL Server Express 2012 I need a collation where ss and ß are not considered the same when comparing strings. Also ä and ae, ö and oe and ü and ue should be considered different respectively. Latin1_General_CI_AS provides the latter, but ss and ß are not distinguished. That is, `WHERE ThatColumn = 'Fass'` would yield both `Fass` and `Faß`.

I would simply stick to BIN/BIN2, but I need case insensitivity. If nothing else works I'll have to use Latin1_General_BIN/Latin1_General_BIN2 and make sure everything is uppercase or lowercase myself. It would mean more work as I need to be able to retrieve the version with proper casing as well.

But if there's a collation that does what I need, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Update:
More information about the requirements: the database contains personal names from a legacy system which only supported ASCII characters. That is, names like Müller and Faß are stored as Mueller and Fass. In the new system the user will have a function to rename those persons, e.g. rename "Mueller" to "Müller". To find the entities that need renaming I need to search for rows containing e.g. "Fass". But as it is now the query also returns "Faß", which is not what I want. I still need/want case insensitivity as the user should be able to search for "fass" and still get "Fass".

There's more to the system, but I can definitively say that I need to distinguish between ss and ß, ä and ae etc.

Comment: That seems an odd requirement. Any reason? Can you expand on it - is it just ss and ß or are there other ligatures/specials that need to be specially treated?

Comment: I've updated the question. I definitively need to be able to distinguish between ss and ß.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS considers 'ss' to be different from 'ß', so it may work for you. It's a legacy collation, so it might create incompatibilities with operating systems and application platforms. It might also have other quirks I don't know of.

A few years ago, I sketched out a kludgy workaround for a similar problem, and you can take a look at it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/341130/-and-ss-are-not-equal). (Click on the "Workarounds (1)" tab.) The problem in that case was regarding uniqueness in a key column, not string comparison results, so to apply it in your situation (and compare two columns to do a single string comparison) might be unfeasible.

Comment: No, sorry, SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS does not work. Here's how I tested it: http://pastebin.com/nEKJk7bX

Comment: Andre, I don't believe your test is adequate. I suspect the database collation is automatically applied to the constant string in your pastebin example, and the comparison is not being made under the column collation. See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5344/6

Comment: Aha! I see now that you are using nvarchar. The SQL collations that specify a code page will not work for you, I think. If you must use nvarchar, I think you may be out of luck.

Comment: You're right, with varchar it works. I'll have to check if I can get away with varchar in this special case. The application will not be used internationally.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. While the need to fall back to varchar isn't that great, of course, but it will work for us for now.