# Case-insensitive primary key of type nvarchar where ß != ss

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, collation, case-insensitive

This question "[Need a case insensitive collation where ss != ß](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351796/need-a-case-insensitive-collation-where-ss-%C3%9F)" solves it for `varchar` type column, but mine has to be `nvarchar`.

As far as I can gather, `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN` differentiates between `ß` and `ss`. But it is also case-sensitive. Mine is a primary key column which also needs to be case INsensitive:

I need e.g. `weiß`/`Weiß` to be considered equal, and also `weiss`/`Weiss`, but NOT `weiß`/`weiss` nor `Weiß`/`Weiss` nor `weiß`/`Weiss` etc.

I've searched a lot for this, and is it really so that I'm out of luck here? There has to be a lot of people in the same situation, I just can't believe this could be unsolvable.

Comment: You are aware that german language rules contradict your requirements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a case insensitive collation where ss != ß](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351796/need-a-case-insensitive-collation-where-ss-%c3%9f)

Comment: @TomTom if you read my question, i refer to exactly that question in the text. It's no good

Comment: @TomTom and as for the language rules, I am not so sure, but at any rate it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It is absolutely not irrelevant. SQL collations generally follow accepted rules. The german language defiens SS and ß to be identical. In fact, you can split the ß into ss if you want - for example for page breaks. If you want them not to be, then you do not need "the right collation", you need to make your own. Which is not supported. Check up on it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Special_characters

Comment: @TomTom I try to keep the question absolutely relevant to the problem at hand, I have my reasons for not treating this according to german language rules and have boiled down the question to only the precisely relevant parts. Which is encouraged here on stackoverflow. I don't like that already we are getting of track with a linguistic discussion.

Comment: Your reason is irrelevant. SQL Server does not support your made up rules AND has no support for custom collation. Which means there is no easy solution for your question. You basically can call MS and ask them to implement your rules. This is not about liunquistic - you may have valid reasons. But as SQL Server only supports OFFICIAL rules, your made up rules leave you with no single collation matching. Whoever designed that made sure he designs it in an ivory tower ignoring limitations of the systems involved.

Comment: @TomTom ok thanks, I guess we have established there is no collation for it, but could there be some workaround? It does not need to be particularly performant or easy. I'm just looking for any solution at all.

Comment: Complex. Bascially make your own proper string in a way that follows your rules. Recode the ß into ss etc. when you need it, then use a binary collation. It will be dirty, but that is about the only approach.

Comment: @TomTom Actually there is a collation for it so SQL Serer does support it and it is "official" and not a "made up rule" by David. There are several that work, all being a subset of `Hungarian_Technical`. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can get to a workaround is using an indexed view to add a unique constraint on `UPPER(ID)` to stop primary key violation that is not picked up by the binary collation used on the actual primary key, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE CollationTest 
(
        ID NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CollationTest_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.CollationTestConstraint
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  ID = UPPER(ID)
    FROM    dbo.CollationTest;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_CollationTestConstraint_ID 
    ON dbo.CollationTestConstraint (ID);
```

Now the following will work as the initial insert:

```
INSERT dbo.CollationTest (ID) VALUES ('weiß');
INSERT dbo.CollationTest (ID) VALUES ('Weiss');
```

But the following will fail:

```
INSERT dbo.CollationTest (ID) VALUES ('Weiß');
INSERT dbo.CollationTest (ID) VALUES ('weiss');
```

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CollationTestConstraint' with unique index 'UQ_CollationTestConstraint_ID'. The duplicate key value is (WEIß).
>
> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CollationTestConstraint' with unique index 'UQ_CollationTestConstraint_ID'. The duplicate key value is (WEISS).

This appears to match your criteria after initial testing.

**EDIT**

I definitely over complicated this, you can achieve the same thing with a computed column and a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE CollationTest 
(
        ID NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL,
        IDUpper AS UPPER(ID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CollationTest_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_CollationTest_IDUpper UNIQUE (IDUpper)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, but it *is* possible as there *is* a collation that handles this naturally (several actually, but all in the same "family"): **Hungarian_Technical_*** (well, minus the CaseSensitive (CS) and Binary (BIN / BIN2) variations). Of course, I'm still not sure this is a good choice for a PK, but no reason it can't be a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

```sql
SELECT tmp.*,
       IIF(tmp.[First] = tmp.[Second] COLLATE Hungarian_Technical_CI_AI,
           N'Equal',
           N'NOT EQUAL') AS [Result]
FROM (
      SELECT N'weiß', N'Weiß', N'Equal'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N'weiss', N'Weiss', N'Equal'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N'weiß', N'weiss', N'NOT Equal'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N'Weiß', N'Weiss', N'NOT Equal'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N'weiß', N'Weiss', N'NOT Equal'
      ) tmp ([First], [Second], [Ideal]);
```

Results:

```
First   Second  Ideal       Result
weiß    Weiß    Equal       Equal
weiss   Weiss   Equal       Equal
weiß    weiss   NOT Equal   NOT EQUAL
Weiß    Weiss   NOT Equal   NOT EQUAL
weiß    Weiss   NOT Equal   NOT EQUAL
```

There are 24 total collations that will work in this manner. You can find them via:

```sql
SELECT hc.*
FROM sys.fn_HelpCollations() hc
WHERE hc.name LIKE N'Hungarian[_]Technical%'
AND hc.name LIKE N'%[_]CI%'
ORDER BY hc.name;
```

They are:

> Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_KS
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_KS_SC
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_KS_WS
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_KS_WS_SC
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_SC Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_WS
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AI_WS_SC Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_KS Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_KS_SC
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_KS_WS
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_SC Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_WS
>   Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_WS_SC Hungarian_Technical_CI_AI
>   Hungarian_Technical_CI_AI_KS Hungarian_Technical_CI_AI_KS_WS
>   Hungarian_Technical_CI_AI_WS Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS
>   Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS_KS Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS_KS_WS
>   Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS_WS

If the version `100` collations are available (meaning: you are using SQL Server 2008 or newer), then use those and not the collations with no version number in their names.

**EDIT:**
I found some additional info on the "Hungarian Technical" collation that might be of interest:

- [MySQL: Hungarian collation](http://marc.info/?l=mysql&m=117026579300485&w=2) -- This is an archive of a listserv discussion by some MySQL developers trying to figure out the specifics of how to implement the collation. Apparently it has some complex rules, due at least in part to needing to equate multiple characters into a single character for sorting (look for section "3. Special digraph/trigraph rule"). This *might* cause some unexpected behavior. The specific letter combinations are noted in that section so at least it makes it easier to set up a test case to help determine if the sorting rules invalidate using this collation.
- [Why are there so many(106) Hungarian collations?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/816c72ca-b328-4a7c-80b1-c9255968caeb/why-are-there-so-many106-hungarian-collations?forum=transactsql) -- This is a discussion on social.msdn that has some interesting info. There is a comment in there by Erland Sommarsko in which he states:

  > I ran a crazy performance test to test all collations in SQL 2008. I had an idle server available, and the test ran for 8-9 days. And Hungarian_Technical came out as the slowest as I recall.

  Given the discussion from the MySQL devs about the complex rules, those test results don't seem all that surprising.

So, both of these items probably should be factored into deciding whether or not to go the easy route of simply setting the NVARCHAR field to one of these Hungarian Technical collations, or going with @GarethD's recommendation of the computed column.

For more info on working with strings and collations, please visit: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)

Comment: Very interesting! I'll test this as well tomorrow. Although it works in the case of weiß, I wonder if there are other quirks about hungarian_technical_*  that will equate other things in an unexpected way..