# Difference in result sets for same collation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'Table1' which has Name column (along with other columns) that stores below values (for example), 10 rows for Name 1 and 10 rows for Name 2.

**Name 1**: Internationale Union öffentlicher Vereinigungen 'Grosse Don-Armee'

**Name 2**: Internationale Union öffentlicher Vereinigungen 'Große Don-Armee'

To keep it simple for this post, I am writing a SELECT query (wrapped in a stored procedure) that groups record by Name and gets the record count as below.

`SELECT Name,COUNT(1) AS CountedRecords FROM Table1 GROUP BY Name`

On database **server 1**, these gives me output as (call it Result set 1) -

| Name | CountedRecords |
| --- | --- |
| Internationale Union öffentlicher Vereinigungen 'Grosse Don-Armee' | 10 |
| Internationale Union öffentlicher Vereinigungen 'Große Don-Armee' | 10 |

On database **server 2**, these gives me output as (call it Result set 2) -

| Name | CountedRecords |
| --- | --- |
| Internationale Union öffentlicher Vereinigungen 'Grosse Don-Armee' | 20 |

The collation is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and table schema is exactly the same on both servers. I can change my query to include COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI for the Name column to make it Accent Insensitive and it would return 1 row with count = 20 in Result set 1, however I am looking for the root cause or possible reason behind this difference in the result sets even when the collation is same on SQL server and database levels, this is resulting into duplicate rows when joining (inner) Result set 1 with Table1 on Name column for further operations.

Is it related to collation or some other underlying SQL/Server/Windows settings?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This looks similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106836/case-insensitive-primary-key-of-type-nvarchar-where-%C3%9F-ss , I tried this one table as NVARCHAR and one as VARCHAR, the VARCHAR one counts them as two sets the NVARCHAR counts them all

Comment: This looks even more like what you want to read, I would consider just setting it to VARCHAR and see how that goes! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871959/choosing-a-binary-collation-that-can-differentiate-between-ss-and-%c3%9f-for-nvar

Comment: You can set collation for your server, database, column. Are all them set equally in both cases?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I would just like to know the root cause as to why with same collation settings on all objects and same table schema in 2 different servers, the result set varies?

Comment: Are there spills into tempdb? As metnioned by @Serg, collations exist at three levels: system (master, msdb, tempdb), database (user databases) and columns. Are the tempdb collations the same on both servers?

Comment: Can you check the LANGUAGE used on the servers and for the user in SQL Server for the connection?

Comment: `select collation_name from sys.columns where name = 'Name' and object_id = OBJECT_ID('Table1')` should be the same result as `select collation_name from sys.databases where database_id = DB_ID()`